# Is it possible to recognize enemies with screenshotbased machine-learning?

Tags: c#, machine-learning, graphics, computer-vision

I'm trying to start coding on a holiday-project that recognizes enemies by analyzing screenshots in lifetime. In my research I read about computer-vision and machine learning. Up until now I only wrote a program that finds a green dot on the screen and moves the pointer towards it. However I'm struggling to figure out how to calculate in distance-based body sizes, shadowing, different player models, only small parts (arms, legs, heads etc.) showing up, finding the difference of dead and alive enemies and wayyy more. For the understanding of my problem I'll add some screenshots. 
Thanks for answering!

http://prntscr.com/fwudav
http://prntscr.com/fwudxm

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Comment: This question needs more help than we can provide. We like helping people, but sometimes you need to help yourself first by reading a book on the language, the on-line documentation, or asking someone you know.  You handed us a rather wide range of issues to handle.  "I'm struggling" is not a problem specification.  Perhaps you could post your best attempt at each of these details, with a description of what's not working.

Answer (score 2):

I'll first give a heads up: This is not a "holiday project". People make 6-7 digit USD salaries researching this.

Instead, I'll answer this with more of an education on how to break up and think about a complex problem like this.

1. Think about it as a human. If you, as a human, can't look at an image and determine what it is you are looking at, then neither can a computer you are trying to teach. Determine what it is that makes the "enemy" an enemy on sight, and then determine what needs to be visible in the image to be able to determine it. Looking for a "person" is difficult, and it won't necessarily make them an "enemy". Find something simpler about them, a logo, a type of hat, etc.
2. Once you know what to look for in the image, the first step is looking at 3d space and perspective. If you know how the image you are looking for can change, you can check for the changes.
3. Apply the same to other changes in a 3d space. Lighting, depth of field, etc.
4. The way to make this faster and easier for a computer is having a lot of just-different-enough sample data to check against.

The technology itself is comparatively new, and finding freely available algorithms and code to work with is not reasonable, but some information about its concepts and the problem can be found.

Some links to learn about what the technology is. Browse and go through the terms on these pages:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_image_search
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perspective_distortion_(photography)